# C# Base or Template Class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, base-class

Ok so I am making a game using XNA, I would like all of the enemies to extend from one base class called "baseEnemy.cs". For example, I would like a zombie to have a class called "zombie.cs" but make it entend the "baseEnemy.cs".

I think I remember being told its would be laid out like:

```
class zombie : baseEnemy
{

}
```

But I am assuming the use of get{} and set{} would help me to change values of current variables in zombies.cs that exist as part of baseEnemy.cs... If that makes sense? I don't understand the usage of get{} and set{} but I have seen it in other languages (such as the code for minecraft) which I would assume are similar in their working.

So, say I have a float for the speed of the enemy... I don't want all the enemies to move at the same speed (zombie's should have a low speed, etc). How could I get the speed from the baseEnemy.cs and set it as the speed in zombie.cs.

Or would I be better just making the variables public in baseEnemy.cs?

Sorry if the above doesn't make much sense, I am not too experienced with XNA or terminology used and therefore I probably sound like I am going round in circles :S

Comment: This is actually not an XNA question, but concerns the C# language as a whole. I would suggest you make yourself familiar with object oriented concepts in C#, specifically inheritance.

Comment: There’s a lot of confusion here about the distinction between classes, objects, files, templates and properties. I don’t really understand the question to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for so called *abstract methods* or *abstract properties*.

```cs
abstract class Enemy
{
    public abstract float GetSpeed();
}

class Zombie : Enemy
{
    public override float GetSpeed()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Note the `abstract` keyword preceding the class name and the method name. The child class has to implement *all* abstract members, if it is not abstract itself. When an abstract member is implemented the `override` keyword must be used.

The `get` `set` syntax you are describing is called a *property*. It is a special C# construct that organizes the getter and/or setter of a field and puts them in a single block. The same example as above using properties:

```cs
abstract class Enemy
{
    public abstract float Speed { get; }
}

class Zombie : Enemy
{
    public override float Speed
    {
        get { return 10; }
    }
}
```